# Alternate between two different colors every 3 elements with only 1 selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of `tr` elements and I want to add CSS on them with the following pattern :

- red
- red
- red
- black
- black
- black
- red
- red
- red
- black

etc.

How can I do this ? for now I've been using :

```
tr:nth-child(6n+1) { color: red; }
tr:nth-child(6n+2) { color: red; }
tr:nth-child(6n+3) { color: red; }
```

... but how can I do it with only 1 selector ?

---

***EDIT : Here is a jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/1s5s05vk/2/***

Comment: you can post your code or jsfiddle link.

Comment: so you want every 6th item and add always 1 more?

Comment: Fairly sure you can't...there is no single selector for that AFAIK..interesting to find out.

Comment: Added a link in the post

Comment: Is this table generated dynamicly? If yes, you could add a class like "red" to any element that has iterator%6 (iterator mod 6) bigger than 3.

Comment: The table is not dynamic, but the point would be to be able to add as many items as possible without editing anything, as the people who are going to use this site doesn't know anything about html or css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work faster with using css.

```
.mytable tr:nth-child(6n+1), .mytable tr:nth-child(6n+2), .mytable tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But if you want, you could use javascript for this.
As I said before.. you could add a class like "red" to any element that has iterator%6 (iterator mod 6) lower than 4.

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++){
    if(i%6 < 4) {
        rows[i].classList.add("red");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this. Maybe it can help you.

```
tr:nth-child(-n+3) {
        background: red;
    }
    tr:nth-child(n+4) {
        background: blue;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do cannot be done with a single selector using CSS alone.

However, you can shorten the definition so you don't repeat code:

```
tr:nth-child(6n+1),
tr:nth-child(6n+2),
tr:nth-child(6n+3) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: @Squiller Edited the answer.

Comment: Well this is litterally what I was thinking. Thanks ! :)